# Get name of tracked 3D model

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, vuforia

First of all, sorry for my English.

I recently started working with xcode and vuforia, what I'm trying to do seems quite simple but I can't do it, I need a print to appear with the name when the 3D model is tracked, the print is not the problem, the problem is getting the name of that target or 3D model

Comment: have you looked at the iOS samples here https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/samples . Surely there should be some code showing how to get the target name.

Comment: I'm using the vuforia sample, and if there is a way, I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by subscribing to the [OnTargetStatusChanged](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1ObserverBehaviour.html#aaccfb9680d9dca08eb26830207d0a1b9) event on each `ObserverBehaviour` you are interested in.

The event receives in input the `ObserverBehaviour` that triggered it and can be used to get the [TargetName](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/sites/default/files/references/unity/classVuforia_1_1ObserverBehaviour.html#a956296549a30b3093652ca8d10008a28).